# React можно ли обойтись без handleChange при биндинге state на контрол

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я начала изучать React недавно до этого использовала Vue. И многие вещи вызывают у меня недоумение.

У меня форма в которой более 50 полей и как я понимаю надо для каждого из этих полей надо прописать свою функцию handleChange.
Есть  ли способ сбиндить поле  формой  без использования функций? 
Можно ли обойтись одной универсальной функцией которая бы меняла state нужному свойству?

Answer (score 0):

Да, почему нет. Стейт можно менять любым способ, нет ни каких ограничений реакта, которые бы не позволили использовать делегирование, что бы ловить изменения формы. Просто повесьте один обработчик на всю форму и в нем уже определяйте что и как менять

Пример в вакууме:

```
render() {
  return (
    <form onChange={this.handleFormChange}>
      {/* здесь поля формы */}
    </form>
  )
}

handleFormChange({target}) {
  const {name, value} = target;
  switch(name) {
     // здесь делаем что хотим
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо инетересно.

Comment: А ни как нельзя обойтись вообще без handleChange? Тот же Vue ведь обходится.

Comment: @Евгения и как он понимает, что нужно делать с полями? Кажется, это либо какой-то плагин, либо все равно нужно описывать обработчик

Comment: Я  же указываю  переменную которую отобразить через поле value. логично  по умолчанию эту же переменную изменять при изменении значения. Так делает например WPF при биндинге. Так делает Vue.

Comment: @Евгения понял, неявно делает все это. Ну что ж, тогда тут нужно все делать ручками) Если не устраивает, то можно поглядеть на библиотеки форм, всякие react-form и так далее. Там это автоматизировано, то что вам нужно)

Comment: Спасибо буду смотреть.